# WatchKit App Submission Error

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

Okay! So here's the deal:

I have made an app with WatchKit and archived it but every time I try to submit it, I get the same error:

ERROR ITMS-90391: "Missing Icons. No icons found for watch application '********.app/PlugIns/******** WatchKit Extension.apex/******** WatchKit App.app'. Please Make Sure that its Info.plist file includes entries for CFBundleIconFiles."

All the *'s are where my app name is which I did not want to share for obvious confidentiality reasons. Here is my Watch App's Info.Plist (NOT THE EXTENSION, THE WATCH APP!!!):

[image: Watch App Info.Plist (WITH ADDED ICON FILES ROW)]

And here is the Watch App's asset folder with the icons (blacked out):

[image: Watch App Asset Folder]

The iPhone App has its own icons in its own asset catalog. Here is the Watch App Target:

[image: Watch App Target]

Archiving it is not a problem until I hit Submit to App Store which makes the error (as printed above) appear. I have:

Cleaning
Making a new project with the same code and stuff to try and fix it
Restarting Xcode
Waited and tried again (a lot of stuff)
Used both Xcode 6.2 and Xcode 6.3 beta 4

I REALLY appreciate the help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should check your Watch App asset's target membership

Comment: @songchenwen What is that and where can I find it? By the way, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I don't know why it worked but it did. I removed the Icon Files row in the Watch App's Info.plist and i selected my dev team in the extension and watch app as it was in the phone app. Then I got rid of all my icons in all of my asset catalogs and then I remade the files (all with unique names) and put them. After that, it worked! NO idea why!

Thanks songchenwen for trying to help! Hope this helps someone!

(By the way you should search Nerdy Lime on the App Store to find my apps)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I tried to archive my watch app and in my case what causing the error was that I putted the required icons for the watch in the asset catalog AppIcon of the iOS project.

So,this is what I have done to remove this error :

1. Select the Images.xcassets file and then select AppIcon image set.
2. Uncheck the Apple Watch box in the Attribute Inspector to remove the required icons for the apple watch.
3. Then I slected the watch app project and in the Images.xcassets file I selected the AppIcon image set and added alll the apple watch icons required there.
4. Clean project and rebuild.

This solution worked for me and removed the error.

Comment: Yeah I heard that a lot but I had them in their own asset catalogs just as they were supposed to be! Anyway this ought to be useful for someone else surfing the web for this answer! Cheers!