# Issue when uploading binary to iTunes Connect with Xcode 9 on High Sierra (ERROR ITMS-90391)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-watch, xcode9

When trying to upload a binary to iTunes connect using XCode 9 (or Application Loader) on High Sierra, I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90391: "Missing Icons. No icons found for watch application ‘AppName/Watch/WatchApp.app'. Make sure that its Info.plist file includes entries for CFBundleIconFiles."

May I note here that the exact same binary was uploaded yesterday, using XCode 9GM on Sierra with no problems.

Things I've already verified/tried:

1. Cleaned project, deleted `DerivedData`, rebooted
2. Asset catalog memberships are correct
3. All the required app icons exist in the appropriate asset catalog
4. The resulting `.xcarchive` appears to contain both the asset files and the `Info.plist` correct entries for the `CFBundleIcons` key
5. I've removed and readded all image files under new names but to no avail.

I'm aware of a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544161/watchkit-app-submission-error) and the most recent discussions in [Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86687). However, none of the solutions suggested seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to upload the IPA with Application Loader?

Comment: @the4kman yes, same error...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an apple bug with xc 9.0 gm on high sierra gm.  Hours of frustration trying to figure this out.

I got around this by unchecking the watch extension target membership on the assets for my watch app and watch extension.   To say that again, both the assets collections for my watch app and watch extension, only have the watch app checked in the target membership list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it happens on the official releases of HSiera/xCode9 and not only in the GM. Also, the workaround does eliminate the error but it also eliminates all assets accessed by the Watch extension, so it's not an option for me