# MacOS HighSierra: Xcode Build App Icon Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store, itunes

I have been facing some issue in Xcode 9 uploading my app to AppStore

the error is

> "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon
> for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format
> for iOS versions >= 7.0."
>
> "WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing Marketing Icon.
> iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps >that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App >Review or Beta App Review.""

and I have searched a lot and I realised too many people had this problem.

But I think mine is somehow different and I think maybe it's about my software update, because I have uploaded the excat same app a few days ago and it was all right.

But now I cant even upload it again.

---

//ANSWER: -

EDIT : I FOUND THE ANSWER THAT WORKED FOR ME

you know this problem doesn’t have same answer for everyone at all because it can be the result of a bug or the excat thing the error says (missing some icons) you should first check all the reasonable solutions like checking your icons etc but in my case ut was just a bug ... and i opened my info.pillist source code in xcode 8 version of the same project (it was for just two days ago and i didnt make any major changes  ) and copy and paste it into my xcode 9 project and it was done...but you have a much easier way too: build your project in Xcode 8.3 ...in the case all of your icons are set you should be good to go

Comment: Your warning message says it all.

Comment: same question asked here, its Mac OS high Sierra bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430910/issue-when-uploading-binary-to-itunes-connect-with-xcode-9-on-high-sierra-error

Comment: just put 120x120 and 1024x1024 png icon in `Images.xcassets` and your problem is solved

Comment: Please check the answer, I have given in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47881859/1637677

Comment: i have the solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885406/4305700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer 
i Replaced all of my Xcode 8 info pilist source code (and yes i handled every needed changes) to Xcode 9 info.pillist and this fixed this problem for me!!!!

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate a little bit more your answer? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: i will answer you as an edit in my question hecause its more than 600 characters

Answer (score 2):

In `Assets.xcassets` > AppIcon  you can find the icon in bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

Just "command+b" your project with Xcode(8.3.3),then i translate the xxx.ipa with  Application Loader ,and it successed. That means you must submit your application with Xcode8.x.x not 9.x.x